# web testing project in visual studio 2015 wont work, why?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, visual-studio-2015

I just started using visual studio 2015 & c# language so I'm a complete newbie. anyway I was trying to write a web testing project with selenium (references) in vs2015 and the first few tutorials were relatively easy to understand, that's what I got:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;

namespace testsite
{

[TestClass]
public class firsttest
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    String url = "http://www.somewabpage.com";

    [TestInitialize]
    public void setup()
    {
        //Starting the browser and visiting the site
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        //after the test
        driver.Quit();

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void testtingsite()
    {
        //Here we write the actual test 
    }
}
}
```

I know it's not much, but the problem is when ever I go to test explorer >> run all then I get this:

------ Run test started ------

Cannot discover test extensions installed by NuGet. The NuGet service is not available. Tests may not be found due to missing test adapter extensions.
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from C:\Users\kkkkkk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testsite\testsite\bin\Debug\testsite.dll
Run started: C:\Users\kkkkkk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testsite\testsite\bin\Debug\testsite.dll
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished

========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:06.5556584) ==========

White it should open the chrome browse, visit the url and then quits chrome, which doesn't happen at all. I re-tested it again with the same result only this time it says in the test explorer window that the test has failed and that's it, when I click on the testsite below the failed test (still in the test explorer window) i get the following message :

Test Name:  testtingsite
Test FullName:  testsite.firsttest.testtingsite
Test Source:    c:\users\kkkkkk\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\testsite\testsite\UnitTest1.cs : line 34
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.1350487

Result StackTrace:
à OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String executableName, Uri downloadUrl) dans c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\DriverService.cs:ligne 243
   à OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService() dans c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Chrome\ChromeDriverService.cs:ligne 146
   à OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options) dans c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver.cs:ligne 80
   à OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor() dans c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver.cs:ligne 71
   à testsite.firsttest.setup() dans c:\users\kkkkkk\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\testsite\testsite\UnitTest1.cs:ligne 19
Result Message: Initialization method testsite.firsttest.setup threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html..

okay that's the message, any ideas on how to solve the issue I really need help );

**modification_1**
so I've modified the code (thanks to @Leon) I added the following `string DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver";` to `[TestClass]` right below the `string url = "http://...";` and also add `DRIVER_PATH` like this `driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH);` in the `[TestInitialize]` but it's still not running the chrome browser!!?

Comment: Did you google the error?

Comment: @JeffC I did, but without much luck you got any ideas that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the problem was like @leon mentioned it in the chromedriver, but although I used his path method (described in modification_1) it didn't work, what actually did work and solved my problem (without changing the first code, before mofication_1) was the installation of the selenium chromedriver from visual studio 2015, I went to references >> right click >> go to manage Nuget package >> and then typed selenium chromedriver in the search bar and boom all I had to do was click on install, internet connection was required. if you can't see the nuget manage packages then you need to [download](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c/file/37502/39/NuGet.Tools.vsix) and install it and then restart visual studio to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You need download chrome driver.

[chrome driver link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

```
string DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\...\chromedriver";

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: I just tried it, now I get the following in the error list:
Error CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'firsttest.DRIVER_PATH' testsite C:\Users\kkkkkk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testsite\testsite\UnitTest1.cs ; at least I don't get the old problem anymore.

Comment: you need to give the driver path if you download it to c:\drivers\Chromedriver.exe DRIVER_PATH should look like "c:\drivers\"

Comment: yeah I did that's the path C:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver but I used the chromedriver.exe version 2.19

Comment: I putted 'string DRIVER_PATH = @c:\\....chromedriver";' in the '[TestClass]' and the rest in the '[TestInitialize]' I actually mistyped a small part of the code, so now I've wrote it just like you said. now I get this error message: Cannot discover test extensions installed by NuGet. The NuGet service is not available. Tests may not be found due to missing test adapter extensions.
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started loading tests from c:... run started: c:..... NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished ; but it still doesn't start the chrome browser!!?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the driver reference as per your browser specification like chromedriver, edgedriver. Please note "not mention any driver path".

```
namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        IWebDriver wb;
        String url = "http://www.yahoo.com";

        [Fact]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            wb = new ChromeDriver();
            wb.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```